# Kotlin: how to get a background's color from Button class?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to get `Int` value of background's color of a button.
I try in this way

```
originalColorOfButton = (button.background.mutate() as ColorDrawable).color
```

but I get an exception of Java RunTime:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.LoginActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable
```

How can I get that?

Answer (score 1):

**Java**:

```
int backgroundColor = ((ColorDrawable)view.getBackground()).getColor();
```

**Kotlin**:

```
val backgroundColor = (view.background as ColorDrawable).color
```

Comment: No( This throws (Kotlin version) the same exception no matter how I try